# Single line regex search in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

When I use "Find Next" to find the next match for a regex in Notepad++ (v. 7.8.6), the match can span several lines. Is there a way to limit the matches to a single line, i.e. to search each line separately?

Comment: It depends on the pattern you are using.

Comment: For example: [^57]{7,}

Comment: Then add `\r\n`: `[^57\r\n]{7,}` - it will match 7 or more chars other than `5`, `7`, CR and LF chars.

Comment: This was just an example. I do not want to complicate the pattern, just turn off the multi-line mode. Just like I would run `pcregrep` without the `-M` option in Linux.

Comment: Then you are out of luck - it is not possible. Use the tools you mentioned then.

Comment: Strange. Notepad++ does it when I search for all matches in the document...

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: What do you mean? The matches do not spill onto the next line. The matches are shown line by line: `Line 1: ...`, `Line 2: ...` etc.

Comment: As you see, it only shows the line where the match started. It does not show you where it ends. Matches are *truncated* in the *Find results* window. Matches in the document pane are highlighted in full.

Comment: Ah, you are right. It is still very difficult to believe this is impossible given the importance of documents where each line signifies a table row.

Comment: It is actually good that NPP allows easy manipulation of multiline content - many more users need exactly that behavior. And you can always get what you want with a correct regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option in Notepad++ to disable matching across multiple lines.

The match texts in the *Find results* window are *truncated*, that does not mean that Notepad++ can be "set" to search within single lines.

The "*`.` matches newline*" option only affects the `.` behavior: if the option is OFF, `.` does not match line break chars by default.

However, `\s` (*any whitespace chars*), `\W` (*any non-word chars*), `[^57]` (*any char but `5` and `7`*) patterns still may "overflow" from line to line because line break chars are among those characters those patterns match.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved one-line-only behavior in Notepad++ regexp by using this approach:

```
^[^'\n]*loopdata.*$
```

I searched lines in a VBA script where 'loopdata' was before ' sign.
I started with [^'] and result included several lines. 
So excluding also line breaks did the job: [^'\n].