# Regex NotePad++ or batch script to find and replace double bracketed text with CR LF -- would prefer NP++

Tags: regex, markdown, notepad++, newline

I managed to do most of my conversion in VBA Macro (Word > txt) but some changes were made also that I could not forego or get around. Unfortunately, I had not been in the habit of using styles and precise formatting in my docs... (Which is why a PanDoc conversion did not "pan" out well, if you'll excuse the pun.)

In my docs, I was using bold text/lines for in-text titles (not Heading 2 alas) but as I was converting mid-sentence one or two-word bold phrases into phrases to go between double square brackets, the makeshift titles/headings were also changed to [[*some title*]] format in the process.

With Find and Replace (a batch script that goes through all files in a folder would also do), I would like to search for each and any number of instances of CRLF [[*some title* CRLF]]CRLF and replace the brackets with ** (to make the title bold), or perhaps ## to make the headings I was missing back in MS Word (I would of course need the line breaks as well).

For better understanding, please see attached picture here:

[image]

I am fairly sure that all instances are similarly syntaxed. If not, I may be able to tailor your regex code to differing instances later on.

As you can see, I was trying to do it in two steps but that's not good, because the second step (which I couldn't even get right) would propably have altered other texts I need intact (there must be sentences that start with double brackets after CRLF).
I would need the two steps in one so that only the targeted double bracketed text would be changed to bold or Heading 2.

Basically what I could not do is: find the proper regex solution for matching double CRLF-ed and square-bracketed text for any number of words than may occupy more than one line and starts with a capital letter. I would need an empty line above and below the title as indicated in the image (the VBA macro somehow made two instances of CRLF and carried the brackets to a new line, which I do not like, either).

EDIT.
In the meantime I managed to cook something up but now I couldn't insert the CRLF in front of the match string. At this point this is not enough as other instances are also changed, even lowercase in-line items, for some reason...

Regex:

```
\[\[([A-Z][\S\s]+?)\]\]
```

Substitution:

```
## $1\r\n
```

https://regex101.com/r/mH6B9N/1

Since then, I made improvements towards what I wanted (I had to test in NotePad++ and not Regex101, for different results), but now in multiple documents I have found match across spill-over lines, as described in here:
[Single line regex search in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61592046/single-line-regex-search-in-notepad)
Is it possible that I cannot do what I want? The problem is having non-title text strings having line-break, double brackets and capitalized letters.

What it looks like in other documents:
[See here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBJtV.jpg)
I circled around with red in image for clarification. See also:
https://regex101.com/r/8XsIGx/1
Is it possible to match a certain word like "címnél" and not execute on that match if that word is present in a line?

Thanks very much in advance,

F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?s)\R\K\[\[((?:(?!\[\[|]]).)*)\R*]](?=\R)
```

Replace with `## $1`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VSt3Q2/2).

**Details**:

- `(?s)` - equivalent of the *`.` matches newline* option
- `\R` - a line break sequence
- `\K` - omit the text matched so far (the newlines)
- `\[\[` - a `[[` text
- `((?:(?!\[\[|]]).)*)` - Group 1: any char, as many as possible occurrences, that does not start a `[[` or `]]` char sequence
- `\R*` - zero or more line breaks
- `]]` - a `]]` text
- `(?=\R)` - immediately to the right, there must be a line break.

Comment: Köszönöm, barátom, it works, but I have the spillover effect that I explained in the edit of my post in the meantime.

Comment: @fl0tt0tt0 You can have a look at the updated solution.

Comment: Testing it on one document has the desired results. Chapeau, Wiktor. I'll do some more tests in the meantime (yes, even in the most complicated documents this wins).

One more thing: how would it look like for changing italics line (embedded in two asterisks for markdown) for line as heading 4? Cheers.

Comment: @fl0tt0tt0 Sorry, not sure about the requirement, sounds like another question. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/VSt3Q2/3) anyway.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.
It's just one asterisk on each side. 
Like so.
https://regex101.com/r/aFTCHS/1
(Sometimes there is also a whitespace, if that changes anything.)
Dziękuję, przyjacielu

Comment: I put up the question here, Wiktor:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73078360/in-notepad-using-regax-how-can-i-change-a-single-line-bracketed-by-asterisks
Cheers